# Android - Java: Initializing ArrayLists from JSON before the type is known

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have series of custom objects that populate a series of custom ArrayAdapters that ultimately populate listviews. In my activities/fragments, I use the same pattern for getting content from a web server, populating a typed arraylist, putting the arraylist into the appropriate adapter and then assigning the adapter to a listview.

What I would like to do is create a pojo that can manage this process for all of the instances where I need this pattern. I don't have a problem with the basics of the logic, rather I'm held up by details.

For example, what I would like to do is this...

```
if (x == y) {
    ArrayList<SpecificObject> a = new ArrayList<SpecificObject>();
} else if (x == z) {
    ArrayList<DifferentObject> a = new ArrayList<DifferentObject>();
} else {
    ArrayList<AnotherObject> a = new ArrayList<AnotherObject>();
}
```

Of course, the problem here is that the compiler suggests that "a" in not initialized. Without getting around this sort of issue, from a conceptual standpoint, I won't be able to create a single pojo that can process the list management.

My questions is this: How can I develop a generic approach to this process while needing to work with any number of specific object types?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to just keep an ArrayList of Objects, and cast when you assign.

```
 ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Then when you need to assign it you could:-

```
if (x = y) {
    assignCall(ArrayList<SpecificObject>) a);
}
...
```

But be aware the cast can't be checked at runtime so you'll get a warning, and ClassCastExceptions if you cast the wrong thing. I normally take note of these warnings that there may be a better way to architect things, but that's up to you ;-)